# How to debug and improve memory consumption on PowerBI Embedded service

Tags: optimization, memory, powerbi, sku

I am current using PowerBI Embedded service from azure with an A1 unit, which is constantly reaching peak memory consumption and thus causing errors in the visualization of production reports.

1) Is there any way to identify which reports/pages/visuals are consuming the largest share of memory?
2) What would be the overall best strategy (on a high-level, general analysis) to reduce required memory? Would that be reducing the amount of data being loaded, reducing the number of pages, reducing the number of visuals, or any other possible strategy?

Comment: Start here: https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/my-power-bi-report-is-slow-what-should-i-do/

Comment: PowerBI Desktop contains a "Performance Analyzer" https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-the-power-bi-performance-analyzer/
This should allow you to see which are the heaviest measures

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the report [Power BI Premium metrics app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-premium-monitor-capacity), this is for capacities, both Premium and Embedded. It will show dataset memory usage and other metrics on the capacity.

> 1) Is there any way to identify which reports/pages/visuals are
>   consuming the largest share of memory?

It will give a good overview of memory usage and whats causing it to time out/evict datasets and reports. Check the link for the full metric lists.

> 2) What would be the overall best strategy (on a high-level, general
>   analysis) to reduce required memory? Would that be reducing the amount
>   of data being loaded, reducing the number of pages, reducing the
>   number of visuals, or any other possible strategy?

Yes reduce dataset sizes, reports that suck in a number of columns but only use a few of them. Look at badly written queries and data models. For visuals, each visual on a page is a query, each query sucks up memory. I've had issues were people have had 30 visuals on a page, reducing them made it a lot quicker.
Look at the usage, are lots of reports being loaded at once, this can lead to dataset evictions, were it is dumped out of memory as other reports are taking priority. The Metric app will give you some pointers to what is happening, you'll have to take it from there and determine the root cause.

As it is an A sku you can set up an Azure Automation/Logic App to scale up and down the sku, or even pause it when needed. Also A1 & 2 are shared capacity as well not dedicated (A3 onwards) so you may have to account for any noisy neighbour issues in the background, but that will not show up on the metric app.

Hope that helps